# Composing URLs for fetching passenger fares from multiple providers

Tags: python, formatting, url

Can someone give me advice, how to make this code look nice?

```
def getFare(self, orig, dest, odate, idate, vid, pax, lang, epi, country_from, country_to):

    def create_link(link_str, API_url, dep_date, ret_date, magic_code, lang):
        '''
        :param link_str: str on which you will use format method
        :param API_url: on which url you should send request
        :param dep_date: departure date as strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
        :param ret_date: arrival date as strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
        :param magic_code: some numbers that identifies the request
        :param lang:
        :return: completed url for request
        '''
        kid_age = ''
        if len(pax['ages']) > 0:
            for age in pax['ages']:
                kid_age += str(age) + ','
            kid_age = kid_age[:-1]
        ages = 0 if kid_age == '' else kid_age
        trip_type = 'false' if idate else 'true'

        created_link = link_str.format(
            url=API_url,
            orig=orig,
            dest=dest,
            dep_date=dep_date,
            ret_date=ret_date,
            adults=pax['a'],
            children=pax['c'] + pax['i'],
            age=ages,
            trip_type=trip_type,
            magic_code=magic_code,
            epi=epi,
            curr=vendor_info[2],
            lang=lang
        )
        return created_link

    if vid == 1:
        user_id = 'some_id'
        new_url = 'http://www.www.www/search/results'
        idate = odate.strftime('%d.%m.%Y') if not idate else idate.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
        format_url = '{url}/dc/{orig}/rc/{dest}/dd/{dep_date}/rd/{ret_date}/noa/{adults}/noc/{children}/ca/{age}/' \
                         'ow/{trip_type}/mid/{magic_code}/curr/{curr}/lang/{lang}'
        url = create_link(format_url, new_url, odate.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'), idate, user_id, lang)
    else:
        two_way = '/rd/%s' % idate.strftime('%d.%m.%Y') if idate else ''
        format_url = 'http://{url}/iws/search/dc/{orig}/rc/{dest}/dd/{dep_date}{ret_date}/' \
                         'noa/{adults}/noc/{children}/ca/{age}/ow/{trip_type}/mr/50/mid/{magic_code}/msparams/{epi}/' \
                         'curr/{curr}/lang/{lang}'
        url = create_link(format_url, vendor_info[0], odate.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'), two_way, vendor_info[1], lang)

    res = requests.get(url, timeout=(3.1, 30))
```

Is this a good idea to put a string and parameters for `format` method in different function and format the string in it?

Comment: What does `vid == 1` mean, and why would the URL not start with `http` in that case?

Comment: @200_success this is just some identification number. Depend on this number the right url will be chosen. `format_url = '{url}/dc...'.format(new_url)` it will start with _http_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely simplify some things. For example, determining the `ages` variable:

```
kid_age = ''
if len(pax['ages']) > 0:
    for age in pax['ages']:
        kid_age += str(age) + ','
    kid_age = kid_age[:-1]
ages = 0 if kid_age == '' else kid_age
```

can be done in a single line and `str.join()`:

```
ages = ','.join(pax['ages']) if pax['ages'] else 0
```

Some other notes:

- docstrings should be enclosed in *triple double quotes*, not single quotes
- I would move `create_link` from out of the function to "helpers" or "libs"
- define your `format_url` format strings as constants and move to the module level
- follow `lower_case_with_underscores` variable and method naming convention
- define your date format as a constant as well - this way, if it changes, you would make a change in a single place only

Answer (score 1):

Some information about my decision.

Put a string and parameters for format method in different function and format the string in it is a **BAD** idea.

It is better to split my `if/else` statement into two functions and make everything there.